# Where can I find live html of my github static webpage?

Tags: html, git, github, repository, github-pages

I've got the live versions of my [github repo](https://github.com/AnupamKhosla/sycoscientistrecords.github.io) working [here](https://sycoscientistrecords.github.io/). For some unknown reason the files in the repo are some older version of the live page. E.g. the actual index.html has this code view-source:https://sycoscientistrecords.github.io/ which is not same as the [index.html in my giyhub repo](https://github.com/AnupamKhosla/sycoscientistrecords.github.io/blob/master/index.html).

Why does the live page have different code from the actual git repo and where is the live page code located in github?

Comment: What is different? The version in git should be identical to the live version, unless your browser has cached the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site https://sycoscientistrecords.github.io/ is served from the repository https://github.com/sycoscientistrecords/sycoscientistrecords.github.io, not from your clone https://github.com/AnupamKhosla/sycoscientistrecords.github.io